# Como adicionar treinamento externo no chatterbot

Tags: python, importação, chatbot, chatterbot

Criei um bot muito simples para aprender a usar o chatterbot. Essa biblioteca já vem com um treinamento, mas eu queria colocar um treinamento extra com a importação de um corpus em português que eu encontrei no github.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = Futaba(
"Terminal",
storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
logic_adapters=[
"chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
"chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
"chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"
],

input_adapter="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
database_uri="../database.db"
)

print("Type something to begin...")

while True:
    try:
        bot_input = bot.get_response(None)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

Isso é tudo o que eu tenho.

Como posso importar esse corpus no meu chatbot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta demorou para vir e provavelmente você já deve ter conseguido, mas só pra ficar registrado:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
bot = ChatBot('bot')
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)
trainer.train('arquivoDeTreino.yml')
```

O arquivo .yml é o arquivo onde fica a conversa que será usada para o treinamento do bot. Caso queira um exemplo de arquivo, use estes: https://github.com/gunthercox/chatterbot-corpus/tree/master/chatterbot_corpus/data/portuguese

Também é possível treinar o bot com um arquivo txt mesmo, onde cada linha é uma sentença vinda do usuário ou do bot, pra isso ao invés de ChatterBotCorpusTrainer, você usa ListTrainer.
Qualquer coisa você pode olhar a documentação do ChatterBot que tem tudo lá explicadinho. https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/training.html